# How to create library or framework for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to create a library in Objective C in XCode, like the MKMapKit framework. How can I create this?

What type of project do I have to create for this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78423/xcode-using-a-custom-framework.

Comment: not duplicate of that as the referenced question is how to USE a framework

Comment: possible duplicate of [How SHOULD you make (and use) static libraries on the iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563623/how-should-you-make-and-use-static-libraries-on-the-iphone)

Comment: thanx for link this really nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't make frameworks for the iPhone, you need to have a static library.

Jeffrey Sambells made a very good [article](http://jeffreysambells.com/2010/04/16/iphone-os-static-library-template) how to do this.

Comment: And if you don't know how to create it, how can you be working on it?

Comment: I am totally not agree with @gcamp. May you explain why we can't make framework library for iPhone if there are lots of 3rd party frameworks (like- Facebook, Twitter, layar.com, Revmob, etc.) already made.

Answer (score 0):

You create a framework project - [Apple dev docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/CreatingFrameworks.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002258-BAJDHDAF)

Comment: this doc is tomuch old ...can u give me some new information for this ?  i want to create freamwork for iphone and ipad application.